# GeoFire Query taking several minutes to respond and causing memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, geofire

I'm having a really strange issue with GeoFire. I'm going to bet that I caused an issue somewhere but right now, with the very limited amount of code change, 2 major issues have come up:

1) GeoFire GFQuery is taking a LONG time to respond. It is taking upwards of 3 minutes for GFQuery to finally return the ONLY key sitting in a small, 300 meter circle. The only code I have added to start this query is this:

```
if (!self.circleQuery) {

    GeoFire *geoFire = [FirebaseUtils GEOFIRE_REF];

    self.circleQuery = [geoFire queryAtLocation:center withRadius:0.3];


    [self.circleQuery observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyEntered withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {



    }];
    [self.circleQuery observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyExited withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {

    }];
    [self.circleQuery observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyMoved withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {

    }];

} else if (![self.circleQuery.center isEqual: center]){
    self.circleQuery.center = center;
}
```

2) With only the code above having been added, I am seeing a major memory leak that unfortunately instruments is not catching. Normally when the app starts up it idles around 8-9 mgbts in memory. After adding the Geofire code, I see a steady increase that will continue growing up and up. I stashed all changes to remove any geofire code and it removes the leak so I konw it has something to do with this. I have a feeling that both of my problems are VERY connected.

Any help or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: It seems whatever I'm doing is also blocking Firebase from making other updates. When this code is implemented, if I delete a child on firebase directly, it fails to pop the childRemoved notification it normally does instantly.

Answer (score 0):

After some further experimentation, I found out that GeoFire does not work well at all if you build it off a Firebase reference to just the base url. By appending "/geofire", or whatever else you might want to call it, to the url, all of my issues went away :). The reason I was using the base url in the first place is that all of the iOS documentation on GeoFire (cocoapods & github) reference the base url and don't say anything about creating a separate node just for geofire. To me this should be made clear...memory leaks and 3 minute response time is a BIG problem.